# How can I use bitter or hard water for cooking and specially in soaking beans?

Tags: beans, water, thawing

How can I use hard water (with a bitter taste) for cooking and especially to soak dry beans.

Normally beans do not soak well in hard (bitter) water. In that case, what should I do?

Comment: Possibly *soaking* raw beans??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most countries, hard water is caused by Calcium and Magnesium Carbonates.

These can be easily *removed* by using an ion-exchange apparatus (best results) or can be *converted* by adding an acid to the water.  In the case of vinegar:

> 2 CH<sub>3</sub>COOH + CaCo<sub>3</sub> → Ca(CH3COO)<sub>2</sub> + CO<sub>2</sub> + H<sub>2</sub>O

So the Calcium is not *gone*: it's just converted to Calcium Acetate *but* that is much more soluble in water than carbonate, so it'll *seem* softer.

The same is true for MgCO<sub>3</sub>.

*How much vinegar and how long does this take?*

Overnight should do the trick unless you live on one of the poles.  **;-)**
How much??? I cannot tell you over the Internet so experiment:

- Start with 20 drops per Litre
- Use less if that's satisfactory until it becomes unsatisfactory.
- then go back up one drop and *that amount* will be the best volume for *your* water...